# iPhone - UIMessage.framework

Tags: sms, message, sendmessage

In an iPhone application, we are supporting sending text messages. For this we have to integrate UIMessage.framework in the application. This feature is supported only in OS 4.0 or above version. In the implementation, however, I have disabled the feature if the device OS is earlier that 4.0. However, the issue I am facing is that for devices earlier than 4.0, tha package cannot be installed, simply because the framework needs is included in the package.

Is there any work-around for this issue? Is it possible to have a build in such a way that only if the OS is 4.0 or higher, this framework is included while for earlier versions, this is not needed. Or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIMessage framework to be weak linked in your application's targets. That way, it's conditionally linked at runtime when needed.